# Solr cannot read UUID field

Tags: java, solr

I am using JPA along with hibernate underneath. Then Import the data into Solr. I am using UUID as id in my tables. The problem is Solr is throwing the following exception whenever I try to import data :

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: TransactionLog doesn't know how to serialize class java.util.UUID; try implementing ObjectResolver?
solr    |   at org.apache.solr.update.TransactionLog$1.resolve(TransactionLog.java:100)
solr    |   at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.writeVal(JavaBinCodec.java:234)
solr    |   at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.writeSolrInputDocument(JavaBinCodec.java:589)
solr    |   at org.apache.solr.update.TransactionLog.write(TransactionLog.java:361)
solr    |   at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateLog.add(UpdateLog.java:482)
solr    |   at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateLog.add(UpdateLog.java:468)
solr    |   at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.doNormalUpdate(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:299)
solr    |   at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc0(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:211)
solr    |   at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:166)
solr    |   at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:67)
solr    |   at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
solr    |   at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:955)
solr    |   at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1110)
solr    |   at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:736)
solr    |   at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessorFactory$LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:103)
solr    |   at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter.upload(SolrWriter.java:74)
solr    |   at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler$1.upload(DataImportHandler.java:254)
solr    |   at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:526)
solr    |   at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:414)
solr    |   at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doDelta(DocBuilder.java:363)
solr    |   at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:224)
solr    |   at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doDeltaImport(DataImporter.java:444)
solr    |   at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:477)
solr    |   at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.lambda$runAsync$0(DataImporter.java:458)
solr    |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My XML config:

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">DIHconfigfile.xml</str>
      <str name="update.chain">uuid</str>
      <!--<str name="update.chain">uuid</str>-->
      <lst name="datasource">
        <str name="type">JdbcDataSource</str>
        <str name="readOnly">true</str>
        <str name="autoCommit">false</str>
        <str name="transactionIsolation">TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</str>
        <str name="holdability">CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT</str>
        <!--      <str name="batchSize">1000</str> -->

        <str name="driver">org.postgresql.Driver</str>
        <str name="url">${solr.cf.jdbc.url}</str>
        <str name="user">${solr.cf.jdbc.user}</str>
        <str name="password">${solr.cf.jdbc.password}</str>
      </lst>
    </lst>

  </requestHandler>
```

My schema file :

```
<field name="entityId"   type="uuid"    required="true"  />
<fieldType name="uuid"    class="solr.UUIDField" indexed="true" />
```

The only workaround to make this work is to add a space to the id so it transform it to a string like this :

```
 <field column="dummy_entityid" name="entityId"   template="${entity.id} "  />
```